# Is it possible to load a template dynamically and include it in render process

Tags: templates, dynamic, playframework

I try to develop a kind of report generator with play framework. every report could have a specific template. A report creator puts all necessary elements including the depending template part into a datavase via a web frontend. If a report rendering starts this action is called

```
public static void report(String name) throws SQLException {
    Report report = Report.find("byName", name).first();
    Template template = TemplateLoader.load("inner_report", report.template);
    request.params.remove("body");
    request.params.remove("name");
    List<Map> result = doSql(report.statement, request.params);
    render(template, result);
}
```

The template could look like this

```
#{extends 'main.html' /}
#{set title:'Scandio Reports Results' /}

#{extends 'inner_report' /}
```

Is it possible to render a dynamic template part with the #{extends /} template tag. Is there a better solution?

Thank you

This question was already posted here https://groups.google.com/d/topic/play-framework/DCSbDjUu4_w/discussion

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use a tag instead of a template? In the tag you can then dissect template and result and render what you need.